# HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages is NULL when first loading IE11/Edge in European countries

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I support an application (c#/asp.net) that uses multiple languages using .Resx files for numerous European countries. Recently, some users upgraded to Windows 10 and thus Internet Explorer 11. Now when they load the application, it defaults the main page to en-US and when they go to a page that calls a function that references `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0]`, it comes back as NULL, thus causing a crash with a NULL reference error.

If they change their language settings in any way (add, remove or move a language up or down), then `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0]` is populated with that top language. However, once they reboot their machine and re-open IE11, then the field is NULL again until they change their settings yet  again.

How can I set/detect the correct language without having the user to change their language settings every time they open IE11 after a reboot?

This error does not happen in Chrome, but some users may not have access to Chrome.

Notes I have discovered from past research and are currently in my project:

All pages have `Culture="auto"` and `UICulture="auto"`;

When first loading the application, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = en-US` (and not their default language); (same goes for `CurrentCulture` as well - both are initially set to `en-US`)

After they change their language settings, then `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` changes to be their set language (e.g.: `fr-CH` for French Swiss);

To summarize: How do I detect IE11's language setting for the user when `Request.UserLanguages` is NULL and when the `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` is defaulting to `en-US` and not their system's language? Is there a workaround for using `Request.UserLanguages`?

I had a user go into Edge and try it out and the same problems occur. The application is not picking up the local culture/language - it is defaults to en-US and not en-UK or fr-CH for example. Also, the application is coded to check different cultures to display dates in the format of the culture, so for Europe, the DD/MM/YYYY format is needed and US - MM/DD/YYYY; currency is also different. So I need to be able to detect the correct culture in Windows 10 without having the user change their language settings to set `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: First, the browser on Windows 10 is Edge, not IE11. IE11 is there only for the extremely few intranet applications that break on modern browsers. Just don't use it, Microsoft itself *actively discourages it* and doesn't support it.

Comment: Second, you don't need to do anything. The browser itself sends the language headers. If it *doesn't*, probably because the user didn't set a preferred language in `Internet Options` in the past and lately, the OS's `Language Settings`, or because they only use `English`, there's nothing you can do. `This error does not happen in Chrome` well, IE added those settings a decade or more before Chrome came out. If you get an exception it's because there's no language header in there

Comment: You can't assume that `UserLanguages` will have any data. You can use `Fiddler` to find whether a request has the appropriate headers and what those values are in Chrome and IE11.

Comment: The user are used to IE 11 and not Edge, and I did see that MS is now telling people to stop using IE. I still want to code backups in case it is used and where the screen won't get a YSOD due to missing data.

Comment: Microsoft is telling people to stop using IE11 since 2016. It's now in the "STOP ALREADY" phase. Even *Edge* has such a small market share that *Microsoft will abandon it* and use Chromium as the rendering engine.

Comment: Regarding this problem though, *don't* assume there are any languages in there. You shouldn't need to check that collection in the first place, .NET checks it when you set `Culture="auto" and UICulture="auto"`. Even if you do, don't just use `UserLanguages[0]`. This can easily break with Chrome as well.

Comment: And check what W3C itself has to say about the `Accept-Language` header in the [By the way](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales#bytheway) section. The users may *not* want to use the language chosen by that header. Eg, they may be travelling, or using different settings at home and at work. *Developers* use English everywere. Our families most certainly don't. You should allow the user to pick the language eg through a drop-down and set it as the request's UI culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IE11 is still usable on Windows 10 and millions of people still use it on 10 and on 7 (and other operatin systems). Please don't suggest/demand that askers ignore IE11 concerns when they have customers who use IE11. There are people who are still required to code in COBOL in 2019; you never know someone else's constraints. Further, Microsoft is abandoning their own *rendering engine* for Edge. They are not "abandoning Edge".